# How to use ffmpeg to concatenate two videos of different aspect ratios?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have two videos, one 640x480 and one 480x640 and I want to use ffmpeg to concatenate them together, but I want the resulting video to be 640x640 with both of the videos letterboxed.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Can you show the complete console output of `ffmpeg -i input1 -i input2`?

Comment: I know if you use -f concat method, it'll take your first resolution and apply it to the second. I imagine you do the same method, but define the starting resolution to be 640x640. You might take a look at padding - as resizing will just stretch the video: http://superuser.com/questions/690021/video-padding-using-ffmpeg/690211

Answer (score -1):

[How To create mosaic with live stream with ffmpeg ( or with xuggle )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12383753/how-to-create-mosaic-with-live-stream-with-ffmpeg-or-with-xuggle)

see above for concat

then read the docs on ffmpeg options for 'pad' and 'crop' paying attention to values that must divide by 2 or some such.

you should be able to do what you want but u may have to do separate experiments on the concat and on the padding/cropping to get all the frame sizes correct.